# If the curse of sun and moon was a myth then why did it work

Tags: plot-explanation, the-vampire-diaries

In season 2 it is said that Klaus made up the curse of the sun and moon so that others will find the requirements to break the curse.

So why were the others suffering from the curse like the vampires could only walk at night and the werewolves could only turn during full moon..??

Answer (score 1):

I only have a [fan wiki](https://vampirediaries.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hybrid_Curse#Breaking_the_Curse) to go from but...

> In short, only one side of the curse could be broken, making the other side permanent. **Elijah revealed to Elena that the sole reason why he and Klaus fabricated all of these various myths of "The Sun and Moon Curse" in so many various different cultures was to ensure that the involved species (werewolves and vampires) would be on the look out for a long-lost moonstone and doppelgänger over the centuries was by making their discovery relevant to those species.**

So the curses affecting Vampires and Werewolves were real but the Sun & Moon curse was not...